# Detect whether operator exists and callable in c++ (considering static_asserts)

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, c++17

Given 2 types `T` and `U` I want to detect whether it's possible to call `operator *` between those to objects (i.e is it possible to write `t * u` where `t` is of type `T` and `u` is of type `U`)

I'm using [c++ detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) but since it's not yet available in my compiler I implemented it myself like this

```
struct nonesuch {
    nonesuch() = delete;
    ~nonesuch() = delete;
    nonesuch(nonesuch const&) = delete;
    void operator=(nonesuch const&) = delete;
};

namespace detail {
template <class Default, class AlwaysVoid, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector {
    using value_t = std::false_type;
    using type = Default;
};

template <class Default, template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
struct detector<Default, std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> {
    using value_t = std::true_type;
    using type = Op<Args...>;
};

} // namespace detail

template <template<class...> class Op, class... Args>
using is_detected = typename detail::detector<nonesuch, void, Op, Args...>::value_t;

template< template<class...> class Op, class... Args >
constexpr bool is_detected_v = is_detected<Op, Args...>::value;
```

Now I have such helper:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
using multiply = decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>());
```

and to detect whether it's callable I call

```
bool can_multiply = is_detected_v<multiply, T, U>
```

It's almost fine , for example this prints 1, 0 as expected

```
std::cout << is_detected_v<multiply, int, int> << std::endl;
std::cout << is_detected_v<multiply, std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> << std::endl;
```

But now I have class

```
template<typename T>
class A {
};

template<typename T>
A<T> operator*(const A<T>&, const A<T>&) {
    static_assert(!std::is_same<bool, T>::value);
    return A<T>();
}
```

here `A<bool>` can't be multiplied by `A<bool>` but my code detects that it's possible

```
std::cout << is_detected_v<multiply, A<bool>, A<bool>> << std::endl; // 1
A<bool>() * A<bool>(); // does't compile
```

So, my question is, how to fix my code to not detect methods when they static_asserted out? I suppose I can replace `static_assert` with some sfinae but I don't want to (because I don't have access and besides static_asserts have better error messages).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, my question is, how to fix my code to not detect methods when they static_asserted out?

You simply can't. That's just one of the downsides of `static_assert` - there is no way to externally verify the validity of an operation. That's because `static_assert` doesn't happen in the "immediate context" of the instantiation of `operator*`, and so SFINAE doesn't apply - it will always be a hard error.

> I suppose I can replace static_assert with some sfinae but I don't want to (because I don't have access and besides static_asserts have better error messages).

I sympathize. But that's basically the trade-off. SFINAE and type checking, or `static_assert` and clearer errors. (Of course in this case you could just write a non-template `A<bool> operator*(A<bool> const&, A<bool> const&)` but that's probably besides the point).

Comment: Explaining why might help (SFINAE checks must be done during overload resolution; forcing every compiler to compile every function and determine if it has any illegal code prior to determining which overload to call would both be hard for compiler writers, and could result in surprising behavior (I preferred `void*` over `T*` because your `T*` code contains a bug leading to an error in code 2 levels nested deep)).  SFINAE checks are a compromise, and even there MSVC falls down *hard* on them.